# Audio not playing properly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

The following code plays the audio correctly on Chrome 88, but on Firefox 85 the audio cuts off and sometimes doesn't even play.

```
window.onload = function() {
    Audio.prototype.stop = function() {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }

    let audio = new Audio("./audio.mp3");
    let count = 0;

    function replay() {
        audio.stop();
        audio.play();
    }

    let button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (count < 10) {
                replay();
                count += 1;
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
                count = 0;
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

How can I fix this so that audio is played correctly in Firefox? All the files needed to reproduce the problem can be found [here](https://github.com/joaobzrr/firefox-audio-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the HTMLMediaElement API is asynchronous by nature and that you can't expect it to be able to sustain navigating every 100ms like that.
Even the setting of `currentTime` is actually async, so with your very short interval you may be requiring the audio to stop even before it had time to start again.

For what you want to do, use the Web Audio API and its AudioBuffer interface, along with [AudioBufferSourceNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) which is a really lite representation of a player, that you can control with extreme precision with very low latency:

```js
(async () => {
  const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  const buffer = await fetch( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/joaobzrr/firefox-audio-problem/audio.mp3" )
    .then( (resp) => resp.ok && resp.arrayBuffer() );
  const audiobuffer = await context.decodeAudioData( buffer );

  document.getElementById( "btn" ).onclick = async (evt) => {
    for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      const buffersource = context.createBufferSource();
      buffersource.buffer = audiobuffer;
      buffersource.connect( context.destination );
      const starttime = context.currentTime + (i * 0.1);
      buffersource.start( starttime, 0, 0.1 );
    }
  };
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mohayonao/promise-decode-audio-data@eb4b1322113b08614634559bc12e6a8163b9cf0c/build/promise-decode-audio-data.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click to start</button>
```

Comment: How would I do I turn `Audio` into an `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Just like I did; you fetch its src as an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: Isn't there a way to this synchronously?

Comment: no. why would you want to do this synchrinously?

Comment: So I can be sure that I would only be playing the audio after it has loaded.

Comment: What are you talking about? Can't you read my example code? Does it look like I'm not waiting for it to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any exprience using `HTMLAudioElement`s,
but the bug doesn't seem to be inside your code.
(Which makes sense, since it does work on Chrome)

[Mozilla MDN's documentation about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) also doesn't show that there is anything Firefox-related that might be unsupported.
(Except for [supporting more than one audio type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics), which I don't think is the case here)

Wierd.

Did you try looking at these questions for answers that might help/guide you to find the answer ?
[**HTML5 audio not working on Firefox**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831625/html5-audio-not-working-on-firefox)
[**HTML5-Audio-tag not playing in Firefox**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113040/html5-audio-tag-not-playing-in-firefox)

Good luck finding the correct fix, comment me when you're done !